# Search bigquery for messageid from my gmail account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, gmail

I want to search bigquery gmail logs for a particular messageid from my email account.

```
function myFunction() {
  // Get the first message in the first thread of your inbox
  var message = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 1)[0].getMessages()[0];
  // Get its ID
  var messageId = message.getId();
  // Now fetch the same message using that ID.
  var messageById = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
  // Should always log true as they should be the same message
  var messageIdRFC2822 = message.getHeader("Message-ID");
  // Get RFC 2822 message ID
  var subject = message.getSubject();
  Logger.log(subject);
  Logger.log(messageIdRFC2822);

  // input RFC2822 message id and subject to query BigQuery
  var projectId = 'gmail-gsuite-logs';
  var request = {
    query: 'SELECT message_info.subject, message_info.rfc2822_message_id, message_info.connection_info.spf_pass, m.name as domain, message_info.connection_info.is_internal FROM `gmail-gsuite-logs.gmail_logs_dataset.daily_20200304`, UNNEST(message_info.connection_info.authenticated_domain) as m WHERE message_info.rfc2822_message_id=messageIdRFC2822 LIMIT 10;',
    useLegacySql: false
  }
  var jobResult = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, "gmail-gsuite-logs");
  var jobId = jobResult.jobReference.jobId;
  Logger.log(jobId);
}
```

As you can see from the above code, I get an error for the following part of query. Is there anyway of making this work. In short I want to query bigquery for a specific messageID.
"message_info.rfc2822_message_id=messageIdRFC2822"

Error I get:
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Unrecognized name: messageIdRFC2822

Comment: what exactly error you get?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Below is the error is I get when running the script.

GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to bigquery.jobs.query failed with error: Unrecognized name: messageIdRFC2822

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WHERE clause in your query should look like below

```
WHERE message_info.rfc2822_message_id="<messageIdRFC2822>"
```

with `<messageIdRFC2822>` to be substituted with actual value of `messageIdRFC2822` that you calculated in your code

Comment: Question related to the above code. The query runs successfully. Is it possible to read the query results values and take action if the value is true.