# Script to auto label email if an email is sent internally is not working as expected

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, gmail, gmail-api

I am writing a google apps script to label emails identified as internal via gsuite gmail logs. The logs are being queried via bigquery as you can see by the code below. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have checked the permission and everything is ok. I really do not want to put the query result into a sheet and then  query the "is_internal" value from sheets. I am open to any suggestions that will make this work and better the code. Thanks in advance for helping out. I

```
function myFunction() {
  // Get the first message in the first thread of your inbox
  var message = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0, 1)[0].getMessages()[0];
  // Get its ID
  var messageId = message.getId();
  // Now fetch the same message using that ID.
  var messageById = GmailApp.getMessageById(messageId);
  // Should always log true as they should be the same message
  var messageIdRFC2822 = message.getHeader("Message-ID");
  // Get RFC 2822 message ID
  var subject = message.getSubject();
  Logger.log(subject);
  Logger.log(messageIdRFC2822);

  // input RFC2822 message id and subject to query BigQuery
  var projectId = 'gmail-gsuite-logs';
  var request = {
    query: 'SELECT message_info.connection_info.is_internal FROM `gmail-gsuite-logs.gmail_logs_dataset.daily_20200304` WHERE message_info.rfc2822_message_id="<xxxxxxxxxxxxx@mail.gmail.com>" LIMIT 1;',
    useLegacySql: false
  }
  var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.query(request, "gmail-gsuite-logs");
  var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;
  var jobTable = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
  var jobList = BigQuery.Jobs.list(projectId);
  // Logger.log(jobId);
  // Logger.log(queryResults);
  // Logger.log(jobTable);
  // Logger.log(jobList);

  // Check on status of the Query Job.
  var sleepTimeMs = 500;
  while (!queryResults.jobComplete) {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    sleepTimeMs *= 2;
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId);
  }

  // Get all the rows of results.
  var rows = queryResults.rows;
  while (queryResults.pageToken) {
    queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.getQueryResults(projectId, jobId, {pageToken: queryResults.pageToken});
    rows = rows.concat(queryResults.rows);
  }

  var data = new Array(rows.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
      var cols = rows[i].f;
      data[i] = new Array(cols.length);
      for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
        data[i][j] = cols[j].v;
      }
    }
  var is_internal = Logger.log(data);
  return data.toString();
  if (is_internal == "[[true]]") {
    var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Safe");
    message.addLabel(label);
    Logger.log('Label added');
  }
  else {
    Logger.log('Label not added')
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, boy! you still have an issue with syntax!! see again - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60820040/5221944

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo.  I fixed it but still the same issue. Not getting errors.

Comment: you still didn't get it!! see again very carefully answer on your previous question!

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I did replace it with the actual message id.

WHERE message_info.rfc2822_message_id="<xxxxxxxxxxxxx@mail.gmail.com>"

Comment: I don't see it - in any case - if yo did it means that you should go and accept/vote-up that answer - make sense? otherwise what / why I should care of your this current question?

Comment: I just did. I am new to stackoverflow and I though upvoting was accepting the answer and did not knew about the tick.

Comment: you supposed to use `rfc2822_message_id="xxxxxxxxxxxxx@mail.gmail.com"` - so you have extra angle brackets